# Is $∃y∀x G(x,y)$ the same as $∃x∀y G(y,x)$ and $∀x∃y G(x,y)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let the predicate G(X,Y) = "x hates y" and x and y are in the domain of everyone at a party.

Do these three expressions mean the same thing? Which do and which don't?:

1. $∃y∀x G(x,y)$
2. $∃x∀y G(y,x)$
3. $∀x∃y G(x,y)$

I assume the order of the quantifiers don't matter so I say $1$ and $3$ are the same, but what about $2$? It flips the quantifiers but it also flips the variables in the predicate to G(y,x). Does that make a difference?

Comment: First two mean the same thing; third one means something else. Compare: For every person x there is a person y such that y is the mother of x; with: There is a person y such that for every person x, y is the mother of x. The names of the variables being quantified don’t matter; you could replace $x$ and $y$ in 1 with  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and it would still say the same thing. Don’t think of 2 as “exchanging order and flipping quantifiers”, think of 2 as “changing the names of the variables in 1”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Awesome thanks, that makes sense. What about the order in G? What if it was $∃y∀xG(x,y)$ and $∃y∀xG(y,x)$ Are these the same?

Comment: They are not because x hates y isn't the same as y hates x.

Comment: Another way to see that (1) and (2) are logically equivalent is to observe that $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables (placeholders). When $(x,y)$ ic changed to $(p,q)$ and $(q,p)$  in (1) and (2), respectively, the two sentences become identical.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 are the same.

In general, if I have two statements $\forall a P(a)$ and $\forall b P(b)$, these statements mean the same thing (similarly for $\exists a P(a)$ and $\exists b P(b)$).

So $\exists y \forall x G(x, y)$ means the same thing as $\exists a \forall x G(x, a)$, which means the same thing as $\exists a \forall b G(b, a)$, which means the same thing as $\exists x \forall b G(b, x)$, which means the same thing as $\exists x \forall y G(y, x)$.

Let me illustrate why 1 and 3 are not the same.

Suppose we have two people, Alice and Bob. And suppose that Alice hates Bob and Bob hates Alice, but neither Bob nor Alice hates themselves.

Then for every $x$, there is some $y$ such that $x$ hates $y$ (in particular, Alice hates Bob and Bob hates Alice). So $\forall x \exists y G(x, y)$ is true.

But there is no single person that everyone hates. Alice does not hate Alice, so it is not true that $\forall x G(x, Alice)$ (since $G(Alice, Alice)$ is false). And Bob similarly does not hate Bob, so $\forall x G(x, Bob)$ is also false. Thus, it is false that $\exists y \forall x G(x, y)$.

In general, you can't switch an existential and a universal quantifier.